# Adding sequence numbers to SAS

Tags: sas

I am importing a table from an Access database into SAS where the sequence column became corrupted. I need to create a new sequence column in SAS. I don't want to re-create the sequence number in Access, as the source tables are replenished on a regular schedule. Is there something like an autonumber column that one can add to SAS?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on SAS-L, or you could search SAS-L from [Lex Jansen's page](http://www.lexjansen.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read in a data set in SAS, `_n_` refers to the observation number. This should work for you:

```
data new;
 set old;
 seqno = _n_;
run;
```

Comment: `_n_` is not the observation number.  It is the number of iterations through the data step loop, which is usually equivalent to the observation number, but not always - depending on what you are doing in the data step, it could be unrelated.  This seems like nitpicking but is important to keep separate so that you don't wonder why things don't work the way you think they should in more complex programs...

Comment: I don't disagree that it will work as described (in a simple datastep), but it is important to not use the language 'observation number' to describe `_n_`, or you end up with confused people posting to SAS-L wondering why their code doesn't work...

Comment: @Joe can you provide an example?  I don't understand the distinction you are making between the observation # and iteration #.  Thanks.

Comment: The classic example is the DoW loop - I will post it as a separate answer since comments do not format nicely.

Comment: thank you itzy, I just needed a simple way to add a new unique row id that can be sub divided into 8 equal parts using modulus.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
data want;
set have;
autonumber+1;
run;
```

There is also `_N_` which is the count of iterations through the data step loop, which in a normal data step is equal to the row number.  It is not written to the dataset but can always be accessed as a normal variable.

Answer (score 3):

A classic example of `_N_` not being identical to the observation number - a DoW loop used to append the sum of a variable to every row for each value of a class variable.  Note at the end that `_N_` does not return the row number, but the iteration number - in this case, the data step loop iterates once for each value of `x`, not once for each row, as the rows are pulled in through a do..until loop.

```
data have;
do x = 1 to 5;
  do y = 1 to 3; 
    z=floor(7*ranuni(7));
    rownum+1;
    output;
  end;
end;
run;

data test;
 do t=1 by 1 until (last.x);
    set have;
    by x;
    sum_z+z;
 end;
 do t=1 by 1 until (last.x);
    set have;
    by x;
    output;
    put x= z= sum_z= _N_= rownum=;
 end;
 sum_z=0;
run;
```

Log:

```
x=1 z=2 sum_z=12 _N_=1 rownum=1
x=1 z=5 sum_z=12 _N_=1 rownum=2
x=1 z=5 sum_z=12 _N_=1 rownum=3
x=2 z=5 sum_z=13 _N_=2 rownum=4
x=2 z=3 sum_z=13 _N_=2 rownum=5
x=2 z=5 sum_z=13 _N_=2 rownum=6
x=3 z=5 sum_z=12 _N_=3 rownum=7
x=3 z=5 sum_z=12 _N_=3 rownum=8
x=3 z=2 sum_z=12 _N_=3 rownum=9
x=4 z=3 sum_z=12 _N_=4 rownum=10
x=4 z=5 sum_z=12 _N_=4 rownum=11
x=4 z=4 sum_z=12 _N_=4 rownum=12
x=5 z=6 sum_z=13 _N_=5 rownum=13
x=5 z=3 sum_z=13 _N_=5 rownum=14
x=5 z=4 sum_z=13 _N_=5 rownum=15
```